# How to change path in the laravel config if It's located in the folder upper then public?

Tags: apache, laravel, php-5.6, virtual-hosts

I have laravel 5 and config file in the config folder and My css located in the resources folder which is a same level with public folder where located index.php. Virtual Host Apache config looks to the public folder as a root site directory, but in this situation I cannot declare correct path from /public/index.php to the resources folder.

From one side I can try easy way and just relocate public folder into root of the laravel, but I don't like this way, any ideas?

Comment: What is the connection with the Nix package manager? Why is that in your tags?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didnt read description of that tag, I thought It's just about nix operation systems, not package manager :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `resource_path('path/to/your/css')`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-resource-path

**EDIT**

The most logical is to include your stylesheets in your public folder though. If you need to style a page, the style is public anyway. So why not put in the public folder. There's 2 options to do this:

1. Do it manually by just copying/moving the files
2. Use an automated tool like Gulp or Laravel's own [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#working-with-stylesheets), which provides a really easy way to copy your assets.

Comment: No problem! Please tag as an answer so other people can benefit :)

Comment: The files are still not publicly available thought. You won't be able to load the, say, styles in a view if you don't have them in public directory. The idea behind the resources folder is that you have editable CSS/SASS/JS files there, which are then compiled into a single minified file with gulp script.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

add this code in public/index.php

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
     return __DIR__;
});
```